# Error Creating Android Widget(Spinner) Dynamically and Flipping it into Horizontal or Vertical

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-spinner

I am creating Spinners and other Widgets Dynamically. The app works fine in either horizontal or Vertical view But if i am flipping from one to another , the application crashes saying that the below spinner has null Pointer exception and force close happening after that

**I don t know whats the problem exactly , i am assuming the entire activity is created starting from onCreate From logs, then why its getting Null Pointer?? (Added that it is working fine in one View)**

Below is the code in Which i am setting Dynamically

```
 sku[lineNo].setOnItemSelectedListener (onSpinnerClick);
```

Here is the onItemSelectedLister For spinner

```
OnItemSelectedListener  onSpinnerClick = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {
        Log.v("This","onclick"+parent.getSelectedItem()+" view "+v.getId()+" pos  "+ //
        position+" id "+id+" parentid "+parent.getId()); // Error happens in this Line
        switch(parent.getId()){
           // do something

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};
```

Here Comes Log Cat Error Messages (first Few Lines)

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.app.Activity.CurActivity$2.onItemSelected(CurActivity.java:1379)
at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:864)
at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:847)
at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:970)
at android.widget.AdapterView.handleDataChanged(AdapterView.java:952)
at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:179)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
```

I hope the information is sufficient. Thanks in advance , Just some Clues will be helpful

Comment: If you are creating any dynamic view and then trying to get its id by using getid then It may create problem. Can you check all your dynamic views are giving proper id.

Comment: On which line do you get the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @BharatSharma So how do you say getId() will be problem

Comment: @Luksprog :  you can find the commented line second part of the code

Comment: actually i have tried it once on surface view.. at that time i have used it in oncreate method and it was coming 0 every time. I dont know exactly what was the problem i had faced but i think in oncreate activity is in creation process so setting id will not effect untill activity  will not completely create.